# How to check if value exists in params.permit?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish what I am trying to do here on my `create` method.

What I have right now works if there are no values, the item is deleted. However, if 1 or more param values exist, it passes and is saved. Not what I needed. I need an all or nothing scenario. I want to save only if all the permitted keys have their value. `params.permit(:name, :description, :copyright)`

Before an entry is saved using `organizations.save!`, I need to make sure none of the params that are permitted are nil or empty.

I search all over and can't seem to narrow down on an answer to my exact issue.

Here is my code:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    query_params = params.permit(:id, :name,)
        if query_params.blank?
          organizations = Organization.all
        else
          organizations = Organization.where(query_params)
        end
        render json: organizations, root: "organizations"  
     end

    def create
    organizations = Organization.new(organization_params)

        if organization_params.present?
          organizations.delete
        else 
          organizations.save!
          render json: organizations
        end
    end

    private
        def organization_params
        params.permit(:name, :description, :copyright)
    end    

end
```

Comment: When you say "I search all over", you should help us understand what "all over" means by giving us an answer *where* you searched, what you tried, tell us why that didn't work. That helps avoid wasting our time as we try to help you. As is, we get to "search all over" also, as we try to help you, slowing our response time, and probably asking questions to see what you did.

Comment: @theTinMan I googled, checked various sites, documentation, etc.

Comment: Thank you but that tells us little. Help us by saying what you tried to help us weed out possibilities. Put that information in the question.

Comment: @theTinMan Sorry. I couldn't really find anything that would hint a solution so the only thing I tested was `organization_params.present?` and now  `organization_params.all? { |k,v| !v.empty? }`, `organization_params.any { |k,v| v.empty? }`, and `organization_params.values.all? { |x| !x.empty? }`

Comment: Then, put that into *your question *. That is important and it needs to be where people trying to help you can easily see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add validations to your model.
From your question i understand that you want to save details only if you get values in all the field, if not you don't want to save, right?. If yes, then adding validations to your model will give you what you wanted.

Add the following to your organization model

```
validates_presence_of :name
validates_presence_of :description
validates_presence_of :copyright
```

by doing so, the user won't be allowed to save the details unless and until all three fields have some value in it.

There is no need to use delete as the incomplete information will not be saved.

for more and advanced info [click here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/211-validations-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

To check none of the values of `organization_params` hash is `empty`, you can do something like this:

```
organization_params.values.all? { |x| !x.empty? }
```

or, this:

```
organization_params.all? { |k,v| !v.empty? }
```

You can also check if any param value is empty:

```
organization_params.any? { |k,v| v.empty? }
```

So, your `create` method can be re-written as:

```
  def create
    organizations = Organization.new(organization_params)

    if organization_params.any? { |k,v| v.empty? }
      # at least one param is empty, so delete the record
      organizations.delete
    else
      # all the params values are present, so save the record
      organizations.save!
      render json: organizations
    end
  end
```

Comment: I tested your code but I get is `true` when I give only `:name` and `:description` values.  I do not get `false` when all key values are present `:name, :description, :copyright`. Although your code make logical sense...

Comment: Reverse the test in the block and use `any?` instead of `all?`. There can be a big difference in processing time when there are a lot of items to check.

Comment: @Awatatah you want to get `false` when all params are present? You want to save the record only if all the params are present, otherwise delete the record, did I get it right?

Comment: @theTinMan `any?` didn't ensure all key values of `params.permit(:name, :description, :copyright)` where present. It only checked to see if a value of any key was present. Same issue I had with `oganization_params.present?`

Comment: Correct @KMRakibulIslam. I want to save only if all the permitted keys have their value. `params.permit(:name, :description, :copyright)`

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I tested your revised code. `if organization_params.any` needs to be `if organization_params.any?` or it throws a `NoMethodError`. this still doesn't work. If only 2 values are given, it still saves.

Comment: That was a typo. I fixed that. Please show your server log when you make this request.